# How to update Openlayers from version v4.3.2-214-gb920b78 to latest version?

Tags: openlayers

I've tried to update version 7.4.0 of open layer on custom application but openlayers stopped working.

I downloaded the latest openlayer version from website: https://openlayers.org/download/
and then updated it with my old ol.css and ol.jss but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Read a long list of upgrade notes https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/changelog/upgrade-notes.md for any changes which may break the old code. Also note that you must set a size for the map div (usually done in css).

This is sufficient for a very simple map to work with v7.4.0

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.4.0/ol.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.4.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```